# Extract all elements of a vector that have the same part in their name

Tags: r

The code:

```
a = rep(1,3)
b = 1:4
c = c(a=a,b=b)
c
# a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 b4 
#  1  1  1  1  2  3  4
```

How can I extract all elements that have a name that starts with `b` ? Is there a quick way to do this? I could loop over all elements and see whether the first element of the name is a `b`, but I wonder if there some quick command to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
c[grep('^b', names(c))]
#  b1 b2 b3 b4 
#  1  2  3  4
```

If we need to separate out the common elements, we can try with `split` after creating a grouping variable using `sub`

```
split(c, sub('\\d+', '', names(c)))
```